# Does openGauss have the full support of GNU Readline?

Tags: open-gauss

Does openGauss have the full support of GNU Readline?

Readline library should allow gsql to remember what command I've entered even from last session. However, when I started a new session, and then I pressed the `up` arrow, nothing happened.

Answer (score 0):

openGauss support readline. You can use it by doing:

1. Compile configure with `--with-readline` option;
2. Using gsql with `-r` option.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).